# Добавить AppDelegate.h в проект

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, objective-c, api

У меня есть приложение написанное на swift в котором я использую одно API. В его документации пример на objective - c. Также я установил podspec с фреймворками где все файлы objective - c. Как я могу добавить в свой проект файл AppDelegate.h , чтобы в проекте был как и раньше основной AppDalegate.swift. Возможно ли это вообще ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен  AppDelegate.h

Для вызова Objective-C кода в Swift Вам нужен [bridging header (документация по этой ссылке)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift)

А пример из документации просто "переведите" на Swift - это просто, большинство вещей практически 1:1.